# Python GUI: tkinter app as live desktop for Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, winapi

I want to create a tkinter application that emulates a desktop background. My main problem is currently to bring the tkinter app behind the desktop icons. I have played with `wm_attributes` and `ctypes.windll.user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, but it still draws the main window above desktop icons.

How can I force my tkinter app to always stay behind the desktop icons? (while still being interactive :D )

This is a small mre for what I try to achieve:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

root = tk.Tk()

# Set the window to be behind everything  <-- not working
ctypes.windll.user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(root.winfo_id(), 0, 0, 1)
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', False)

# Create a canvas to display the GUI
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

# Add some widgets to the canvas
label = tk.Label(canvas, text="This is a Tkinter screen behind everything.")
label.pack()

# Start the GUI loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Even if you put your window behind desktop it will not be **interactive**

Comment: Try using [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/1f81457fa8288f247db9d944dfbea22c2136613d/src/bettertk/notitlebartk_win.py#L59) function in place of your `root.winfo_id()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you for the link! Unfortunately, although `get_handle(root)` actually returns some int-value, the tkinter screen is rendered above the icons (I copied the content of your linked file from start to the class `Draggable`)

Comment: @Module_art Sadge, but thanks! I will try sth else then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported.

[Active Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop) lived a short life and was permanently removed with the introduction of Windows XP. Today, there is no supported interface to render an (interactive) desktop background.

If you insist on getting this done, the support burden is on you. To get there, you will want to do a bunch of reverse engineering. By the time you understand the problem you need to solve, you won't be assuming Python to be part of the solution.